# Using ReplaceAllString and ToUpper not Working

Tags: go

What I'm doing wrong? Why ToUpper isn't working?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    r := regexp.MustCompile("(\\w)(\\w+)")

    // Getting "sometext" instead of "SomeText"
    res := r.ReplaceAllString("some text", strings.ToUpper("$1") + "$2")

    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Comment: It is working. `strings.ToUpper("$1") == "$1"`.

Comment: @isbadawi don't understand, I'm expecting strings.ToUpper("$1") != "$1". What am I missing here?

Comment: You're uppercasing `"$1"`, which is already uppercase, so you get back `"$1"`. This happens before the call to `ReplaceAllString`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `$1` and `$2` like that I'm afraid!

I think you are trying to turn "some text" into "SomeText".

[Here is an alternative solution](http://play.golang.org/p/YBXpAKRQDC)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`\s*\w+\s*`)
    res := r.ReplaceAllStringFunc("some text", func(s string) string {
        return strings.Title(strings.TrimSpace(s))
    })

    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strings.ToUpper("$1")` doesn't appear like it's working because the input is not what you think it is.  Let's break down your program into a more readable fashion to uncover what the issue is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    r := regexp.MustCompile("(\\w)(\\w+)")

    upper := strings.ToUpper("$1")  // upper == upcase("$1") == "$1"

    res := r.ReplaceAllString("some text", upper + "$2") // passing in "$1 $2"

    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

As you can see, the `$1` is not substituted yet when you call `strings.ToUpper`.

Unfortunately, you can't really use `strings.ReplaceAllString` to accomplish what you're trying to do, however, as Nick Craig-Wood mentioned in another answer, you can use `strings.ReplaceAllStringFunc` to [accomplish the desired behavior](http://play.golang.org/p/vl9qSC_gqr).

Comment: Thanks @noj for the thorough explanation :)